# how to use python to read .cbr files?

Tags: python

How can i use python to read `.cbr/.cbt` files?

cbr/cbt files are a RAR archive format used for comic book files.

Comment: -1 This is a very unclear and unspecific question. You should indicate what your exact problem is, what you have tried so far, and what kind of solution you are looking for.

Comment: @Pekka, @Space_Cowboy: cbr are comic book archive files. OP is just asking for ways to read files with this format via Python. This is a perfectly valid question IMO. (I upvoted just to nullify the unfair downvote.)

Comment: @Missing Faktor I didn't downvote, but was very tempted to. When asking questions regarding exotic file formats, adding some more info is mandatory (especially since file extensions almost always have multiple meanings.)

Comment: @Pekka   CBR is some what well known and support by multiple comic-viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.cbr` is a RAR archive. `.cbt` is a TAR archive. You can use standard [`tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) module for latter but you need to use `rar`/`unrar` for former. You can look for the code you need in [comix](http://comix.sourceforge.net/) (more precisely, `archive.py`).